# Flutter desing: CupertinoApp and MaterialApp in the same project

Tags: flutter, app-store, flutter-cupertino, materialapp

Is it a good practice desing an App in Flutter (for IOS and Android) to use CupertinoApp and MaterialApp in the same project?

Apparently it works as expected in the simulators (Xcode and AndroidStudio simulator), but i would like to know if it will be accepted by AppStore and PlayStore reviewers and it also will work in real devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As my experience you can not use cupertino app instead of material app in android real device,
So Material app is best option for work in Android and iOS.

**If you are try to use cupertinoApp and run in Android Real Device then you will getting error like this.**

[image]

Comment: I created and .apk file of the Flutter project that ueses CupertinoApp and MaterialApp, installed it in an Android real smartphone and it works with no erros.

Comment: yes but you used both of that so you are getting no error and I tried with only cupertinoApp instead of material app,
So You can not use cupertinoApp without use of materialApp